# ModernIE VM Windows 10 for Parallels won't run

Tags: internet-explorer-11, osx-yosemite, parallels, windows-10, modern.ie

I'm attempting to get the Modern IE VM for Windows 10 with IE 11  to run in Parallels 10.2 on Mac OS X 10.10.3.  I have downloaded it multiple times, using both the single zip and multiple file methods.  When I start it I get

- Recovery Your PC/Device needs to be repaired.
- The digital signature couldn't be verified.
- File: \Windows\system32\winload.exe
- Error code: 0xc0000428
- Press Enter to try again. Press F8 for Startup Settings.

No action that I can take will allow this to function.

I should note that I have most (all?) of the other VMs installed, and they all work fine.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue in VirtualBox 4.3.26 on ArchLinux.

Comment: Exact same message on OS X 10.10.3 using VMWare Fusion 6.0.6. It's probably best to take this up with Microsoft.

Comment: Looks like an issue has already been opened with Microsoft: https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/1326730/problem-with-windows-10-on-windows-7-virtual-box

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This suggests it has something to do with time: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-2636035/winload-exe-verified-error-code-0xc0000428.html

Setting my host systems time to something before April 15th worked for me.

Comment: I'm surprised that actually worked. Set my system time to April 8th, 2015. The modern.ie image seems to expire on April 15th, so make sure to take a snapshot.

Comment: Yeah this does work. Odd. Will make a snapshot and then change the hoste date (OSX Mavericks) back to the current date.